# PowerShell: SendKeys not working if executed via scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduler

**Update:**
Context of my problem: I am a member of small group of flight simulator fans. To train together we run a P3D multiplayer server. Since we train during the day as well as in the evening I have created a powershell script that changes daily between day and evening mode. To do this manually is out of the question since it would mean restart P3D twice every day! The P3D process allows to be started automatically in multiplayer mode with a given flight file. The only problem is that P3D remains stopped after the startup; to unstop it, the character 'p' has to typed on the keyboard. The multiplayer server is a Windows 10 PC that run unattended in an kind of server room environment. Security is no issue with the running of the multiplayer server.

The PowerShell script works fine if started manually. Since the PS script needs admin rights I start it via a cmd script with the following content:

```
SET ScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ScriptsDirectory%StartP3DProcess.ps1
PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

The PowerShell script edits 3 files (2x XML, 1x flat) then starts a process and after some delay sends the character 'p' to the process.

```
# Setup date and time in flight file
$result = SetDateTimeInFlightFile -eveningOffsetHour $eveningOffsetHour -flightFileSpec $flightFileSpec
    
# Setup required TacPack state
$result = SetTacPackState -tacPackState $controlData[$controlTacPackState] -tacPackFileSpec $tacPackFileSpec

# Update session state description in multiplayer configuration file
$result = SetSessionStatus -mpCfgFileSpec $startCfgSpec

# Start P3D Server
Start-Process -FilePath $P3DFileSpec -ArgumentList $P3DArgs

# Set the started P3D process operational
Start-Sleep -s 60 # wait until process is started up

# Send 'p' to P3D server
$result = SendCommandToProcess -processName $P3DFileExe -command 'p'
```

Since the PS script should run twice a day (at 7h00 and 19h00) I setup a scheduler task to run the cmd script. The PS script started via the sheduler works fine with one execption: The sending of the character 'p' does not work. The function that send the character to the specified process looks as follows ($processId contains correct process id, $command 'p'):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($processId)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($command)
```

The working environment is a 'server' that runs Windows 10 Pro without any normal user on the system (there is only one user account 'admin' for administration purposes). Using the integrated logfile writing I have verified that in both cases (scheduler and manually run):

- The PS script runs under the correct user and has admin rights
- $processId points to the correct process (PID checked via task manager)
- The delay of 60 seconds between process start and sending 'p' is more than enough
- PowerShell produces no error output

What is fooling me? Thanks for any hints and your help
Hannes

Comment: is the code running as the current logged in user? if not, then you may be running in a _non-interactive_ session ... and i don't think there is anything for sendkeys to send a key to.

Comment: To Lee_Dailey: Yes it is. The scheduler task is set to run only if the one user defined on the system (admin) is logged in. Also the taks is marked to to run with highest priviledges

Comment: For security reasons, it does not work if the admin user is not manually (!) logged in (meaning: you can see the desktop and are able to interact with application windows).
Its a bad idea anyway. So much can go wrong, when you blindly send keys to windows. What are you trying to automate anyway?

Comment: Ok judging from your profile, this isn't a work thing, so security is not an issue. You're trying to automate Flight Simulator, right? So build a dummy windows form, with a timer object and start the script manually. Here is an example: https://bytecookie.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/gui-creation-with-powershell-part-2-the-notify-icon-or-how-to-make-your-own-hdd-health-monitor/ Different task, but same principle.

Comment: Hi Rob: Correct security is not a topic. I am a member of small group of flight simulator fans. To train together we run a P3D multiplayer server. Since we train during the day as well as in the evening I have created a powershell script that canges daily between day and evening mode. To do this manually is out of the question since it would mean restart P3D twice every day! The P3D process allows to be started automatically in multiplayer mode with a given flight file. Only problem is that P3D remains suspended after the startup; the 'p' unsuspends it. Can you help me?

Comment: @HannesSchmid - thank you for the added info. at this point i am out of ideas ... so i will go back to lurking. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @HannesSchmid You should add this to the problem description.

Comment: @Rob - Have updated the context of the problem in my initial description.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of this is to simply resume a suspended process, you can either use [PsSuspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) or the [PoshInternals](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshInternals/1.0.34) Module, which provides a suspend/resume process function.

Comment: '@Rob: Unfortunately I used a misleading term to describe the state of P3D after the startup. More precise would be the term 'Stopped'. To unstop P3D the character 'p' has to be typed at the keyboard.